# Ansible variables with multiple values in conditional statements

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

I am using Ansible to provision VMs in my environment which works great, but we are currently reworking the playbook to place VMs in specific clusters/datastores based on the name assigned when standing them up with the `vmware_guest`module.

Our server names look something like the following. (P=Production, S=Staging, Proceeding characters A=Primary, B/C=Secondaries etc). We have corresponding clusters and datastores for primaries, secondaries, staging, etc.

`P-WEB01-A`
`P-WEB01-B`
`S-WEB01-A`
`S-WEB01-B`

At the beginning of the playbooks we specify a variable titled `vm_name`

Using the `when:` statement I'm trying to do something along the lines of this

`when: "'P-' in {{vm_name}}" and {{vm_name}}[-1] == "A" or {{vm_name}}[-1] == "1" or {{vm_name}}[-1] == "2" or {{vm_name}}[-1] == "3" or {{vm_name}}[-1] == "4"`

But I would like to condense it for appearance sake to look something like this

`when: "'P-' in {{vm_name}}" and "{{vm_name}}[-1] == 'A', '1', '2', '3', '4'"`

or

`when: "'P-' in {{vm_name}}" and {{vm_name}}[-1] == "B" or {{vm_name}}[-1] == "C"` looking like the following

`when: "'P-' in {{vm_name}}" and "{{vm_name}}[-1] == 'B', 'C'"`

I just don't know if the following would work and am having some trouble finding a similar situation.

Maybe there is a better way to go about it like a variable file or maybe using `vmware_vmotion` to migrate the server after it has been stood up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *I would like to condense it for appearance sake to look something like this*

```
when: "'P-' in {{vm_name}}" and "{{vm_name}}[-1] == 'A', '1', '2', '3', '4'"
```

A: The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_hosts: ['P-WEB01-A', 'P-WEB01-B', 'S-WEB01-A', 'S-WEB01-B']
    my_sufix: ['A', '1', '2', '3', '4']
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "[OK] {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_hosts }}"
      when: item[0:2] == "P-" and item[-1] in my_sufix
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=P-WEB01-A) => 
  msg: '[OK] P-WEB01-A'
skipping: [localhost] => (item=P-WEB01-B) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=S-WEB01-A) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=S-WEB01-B)
```

Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: This will work great. I really like how you stored them all in a variable and check against that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you can condense your checks as,

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - vm_name: "P-WEB01-1"
    - vm_name1: "P-WEB01-B"
  tasks:
    - name: Check regex
      debug:
        msg: "Check 1 passed : {{ vm_name }}"
      when: vm_name | regex_search("^P-.*-[A|1|2|3|4]")

    - name: Check regex
      debug:
        msg: "Check 2 passed : {{ vm_name1 }}"
      when: vm_name1 | regex_search("^P-.*-[B|C]")
```

I have used regex_search filter to match the value of vm_name.

I have provided a regex for both conditions.

Comment: This would work great as well. I'll definitely use this in the future. Thank you.